# In an Azure data flow, can joins and lookups only be done between datasets of the same type?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

It's my understanding that lookups and joins in Azure data flows can only be performed between identical/similar formats. For example, between dedicated SQL pool and Azure SQL. In other words, I cannot pair up a dedicated SQL pool and parquet. Am I correct? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

`Joins` and `lookup` will only work if the data types of 2 datasets columns that are being matched are both compatible.

You can compare any 2 datasets if the column types are compatible with each other.

**Example:**

String type column can only be joined to string type column. If both columns are not of the same type, it gives an error.

[image]